# Wordpress Plugin Class setup Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

Im making a plugin using Class , I need to run some Ajax on the Front end. All scripts are queue up correctly. when i trigger the call, i get 400 error.

```
class CCYTFeatured {

public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'cc_yt_scripts' ));
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_cc_get_featured_yt', array( $this, 'cc_get_featured_yt' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cc_get_featured_yt', array( $this, 'cc_get_featured_yt' ) );

} 
public function cc_yt_scripts() {

    // JAVASCRIPT
    wp_register_script( 'cc_yt_script',
        plugins_url( '/js/cc_yt.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery'),
        cc_yt_version(),
        true
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'cc_yt_script',
        'cc_yt_ajax',
        array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('cc_yt_script');

}
public function cc_get_featured_yt(){
    echo 'SUCCESS!';
    die();
}
```

My ajax call is:

```
function start_yt(){
jQuery('#cc_yt_light_wrap').show();
// REGISTER NEW ENTRY USING AJAX
jQuery.ajax({
    url: cc_yt_ajax.ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action : 'cc_get_featured_yt',
    },
    async: true,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
}
```

Thanks for your help! X)

Comment: When you say you get a 400. Are you getting a 404, or some other 400?

Comment: @trattles - I get the following::

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Do you happen to have access to your server logs? If so, those logs may give some insight as to why it's a bad request. I have an application firewall that responds that way to certain inputs it does not expect to see for instance. For what it's worth, this code _should_ work so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is ok,

The way i was calling the class was wrong.

I was calling this inside a theme. Instead, i created a new method and moved everything from __construct().

Started my class and called the method inside the plugin file. After i started the class again and only called the needed method inside my theme. Worked perfectly.

Comment: bro, is there a reason why we can't call it insiide the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Change the method name from `cc_get_featured_yt` to `get_featured`, and change the method name everywhere in your class. 
and then in the ajaxcall you put this code:

```
data: {
    action : 'featured_yt',
}
```

I think the `get` in the methodname is a keyword. This worked for me.

Comment: no luck,  Note that my class is inside a plugin.  This gets called inside a theme. The scripts and styles are able to load with no problem.   I've tried adding nonce to authenticate but no luck.. 

This is the call:  http://www.caseclub.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cc_yt_featured&security=79e39910b8&post=bananas